# How to replace characters in many texts files with c#

Tags: c#, text, replace, text-files

I'm trying to read many textfiles and replace characters in each file, my code as below but when I return to originals textfiles I found that nothing change!. another question if I want to add the quotation i.e ("") to string named as stripchars1 to be replaced 
 how to do that?

```
 string[] Paths = Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.txt");
 string[] stripchars1={"<","?","."};
 string[] chars2={"s","w","n"};

        foreach (string file in Paths)
        {
            TextReader objstream = new StreamReader(file);


            foreach (string character in stripchars1)
            {

                file.Replace(character, " ");

            }

          foreach (string character in chars2)
            {

                file.Replace(character, "h");

            }

        }
```

Comment: You aren't modifying the file at all. You are modifying the filename, which is stored in the variable called `file`.

Comment: You haven't even read any files yet.  Just because you call your variable `file` it doesn't mean you are dealing with one.  You need to look at how to read and write files.

Comment: @stybl yes I think you're right but do you have an idea how to access the content of each file? thank you

Comment: Try asking the mighty google first. There are plenty of guides on I/O that you can follow.

Comment: @DarrenYoung I know how to read and write my problem is how to modify the content of each file to replace

Comment: @stybl I asked google but I didn't find that help me

Comment: @dany try to solve one problem at a time. First thing is to learn how to read the file. Replacing text comes much later. Try searching for "read file in c#" on google and read the first result. Remember, a program is a series of steps. If a step is too high, divide it in smaller steps.

Comment: @dany Looking at your code, no you don't know how to read and write a file.

Comment: @jitendragarg thank you for you kind. I appreciate your advice

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your code, so that it does what you intended to do.

I used method *StreamWriter.ReadToEnd()* to read all content of file into a string. An additional StreamWriter-object is necessary to write result into another file, which has filename suffixed with *.new*. Please note

- that with a StreamReader you can only read the content of a file, you cannot write with a StreamReader.
- that the writer-object needs to write into a different file, since the file is already opened by StreamReader
- *Using* makes sure that unmanaged objects are relaese as early as possible.

Answer to 2nd question: You can use backslah **\** in order to have double quotes (*"*) in a string.

```
        string[] Paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
        string[] stripchars1 = { "<", "?", ".","\"" };
        string[] chars2 = { "s", "w", "n" };

        foreach (string file in Paths)
        {
            using (StreamReader objstream = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                using (StreamWriter objstream2 = new StreamWriter(file + ".new"))
                {
                    string s = objstream.ReadToEnd();

                    foreach (string character in stripchars1)
                    {
                        s = s.Replace(character, " ");
                    }

                    foreach (string character in chars2)
                    {
                        s = s.Replace(character, "h");
                    }

                    objstream2.Write(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks a lot your answer help me.

Comment: Please confirm my answer as the right one. (green check mark)

Comment: I did that before but I didn't know what the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    string[] Paths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
    string[] stripchars1 = { "<", "?", "." };
    string[] chars2 = { "s", "w", "n" };

    foreach (string file in Paths)
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(file);

        foreach (string character in stripchars1)
        {
            text = text.Replace(character, " ");
        }

        foreach (string character in chars2)
        {
            text = text.Replace(character, "h");
        }

        File.WriteAllText(file, text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here's another version of the same thing but adding some support for threading with multiple cores as well as the use of the static *ReadAllText* and *WriteAllText* methods which handle the disposing of their own streams internally.

```
    char[] stripchars1 = { '<', '?', '.', '\'' };
    char[] chars2 = { 's', 'w', 'n' };

    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt"), file =>
    {
        File.WriteAllText(string.Format("{0}_new.txt", file), 
            string.Join("", File.ReadAllText(file).Select(c => stripchars1.Contains(c) ? ' ' : chars2.Contains(c) ? 'h' : c)));
    });
```